# Share Text via intent to application accounts

Tags: android, android-intent, share

Updating `AndroidManifest.xml` with

`<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

add the application to the share list for text type data for example.
But how can i add option to choose different accounts from my application to share with ? for example :[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is referred to as "[Direct Share](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#direct-share)", added in Android 6.0.
The basics steps are:

- Create a subclass of [`ChooserTargetService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/chooser/ChooserTargetService.html)
- In [that class' `onGetChooserTargets()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/chooser/ChooserTargetService.html#onGetChooserTargets(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.content.IntentFilter)), return a list of `ChooserTarget` objects that represent the specific accounts/tags/whatever that you want to let the user share to
- Add the service to your manifest, with `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE"` and a `ChooserTargetService` `<intent-filter>`
- Add a `meta-data` to your `ACTION_SEND` activity's `<intent-filter>`, pointing to your `ChooserTargetService`

Then, when the user does something that invokes `ACTION_SEND`, where your activity is a candidate, an Android 6.0+ device will also show your direct share targets.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.0/Intents/FauxSenderMNC) demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i had to wait at least 5 minutes in order to accept